# bin deploy database clients in IIS

Tags: c#, oracle, iis, db2, sybase

In an IIS7+ shared hosting environment, we have applications that all require different database connectivity and versions. We've run into this in the past where one will require an upgrade, which will then break the connections for other applications residing on the same server. Is it possible to force an application to fully bin deploy any needed database connectivity drivers, or do you HAVE to have the full clients installed? Mainly

1) Oracle
2) MS SQL
3) Db2
4) Sybase

We even have one application that is trying to connect to all four of them, so I am wondering if it is possible to segregate different versions of the same clients on one machine somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:
Both.
Sometimes you break applications and sometimes it works fine, when you install multiple versions. For each driver, it has to be different approach. Lets say, Sql Server drivers live happily together for different versions. Then, there is Oracle. And if the Oracle client doesn't correspond ODP.net you use, it will brake the application. So, there you need a research and may be it is possible (and I think, it is) to have multiple Ora clients. There may be required order of installation, where older version installed first.

I don't know about DB2 and Sybase but all 4 drivers can live together on same machine. You still do want to deploy everything into your bin, but client still have to be installed. Such as in case with Oracle, where you have Oracle.DataAccess.dll in your bin but you still need client software.

Comment: So for example with Oracle, can an application bin deploy the oracle instant client and then they can control that way what version they have? If they did that, we wouldn't need the full client on the machine right? Maybe I'm not understanding fully.

Comment: Oracle claims: "Instant Client allows you to run your applications without installing the standard Oracle client or having an ORACLE_HOME". I tried and it didn't work for me until I installed just a regular client. Then everything magically started to work.

Comment: I guess, you still need installing Instant client package because it has to have something that connects you to Oracle. Then you bin deploy your ODP.net